# using oembed - json responses (in client side javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp, oembed

If an oembed provider is only outputting json and xml, does that mean it is impossible to use this via client side javascript? ($.ajax request to the provider)?

Can we only use oembed providers that allow for a jsonp callback in javascript?

Thanks,
Wesley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot use ajax across different domains.
Jsonp is an option, other option is to have a server side script which will fetch the data from the provider and then make an ajax call to that script to return the fetched data

Comment: Thanks, I find it a bit weird that jsonp was not added to the oembed spec... I mean, oembed is _always_ cross domain.. I guess they don't really want you using it in javascript, but more in a server side language so you can cache the result?

Comment: I got around this by using YQL in my Jquery oembed library at  https://github.com/starfishmod/jquery-oembed-all - it might help you